# Why is the auth token not displayed with CURL?

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I have this code and I want the auth token to be echo'd onto the screen. However, only '`start gettoken`' and '`test after curl`' is being displayed. And the token is missing. What is wrong in the code? Is the curl request being executed at all?

```
  function getToken1() {
    echo "start gettoken";  
    $jsonStr = http_build_query(Array(
        "client_id" => "**",
        "scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        "client_secret" => "**",
        "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
    ));
    $headers = Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    $ch = curl_init("https://login.microsoftonline.com/**.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonStr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "test after curl";

    echo $token;
    return $token;


}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what does `curl_getinfo()` function returns?

Comment: it doesnt display anything

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi i tried $info = curl_getinfo($ch). and then echo $info

Comment: Ok, What about setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true and see if its sent with header!?

Comment: like this? > 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);'

Comment: Yes, as you did. see hows the results is different now, and check if you see the auth token.

Comment: ive added that but still dont see the token :(

Comment: Yeah, I think its about some security techniques Microsoft uses, so you wont be able to fetch auth token with easy.